# How to delete all translations when deleting a node using default language?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I'm trying to delete all translations when deleting a node using default language?

For that purpose, I am using the [hook_node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7), but I am not able to invoke [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7) from it. It cause a fatal error and the process can't terminate. Even the first node I am deleting isn't deleted preoperly.

```
 function hook_node_delete($node){
        $translation_list = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
        $default_language = language_default()->language;

        if($translation_list!=""){
           foreach($translation_list as $translation_list_item){    
              if ($translation_list_item->language!=$default_language){
                  node_delete($translation_list_item->nid);
              }
           };
        };
    }
```

So I am forced to simply unpublish the translations by doing something like that:

```
 function hook_node_delete($node){
                $translation_list = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
                $default_language = language_default()->language;

                if($translation_list!=""){
                   foreach($translation_list as $translation_list_item){    
                      if ($translation_list_item->language!=$default_language){
                          $node_translated = node_load($translation_list_item->nid);
                          $node_translated->status = 0;
                          node_save($node_translated);
                      }
                   };
                };
            }
```

Why can I not invoke [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/7) from [hook_node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Gert van den buijs" answer doesn't work for me. So I managed to do it by deleting the content directly with db_delete. I'm not sure it's the best way to do it but at least it works.

Like that, hook_node_delete isn't called recursively and the function can terminate properly.

```
function hook_node_delete($node){
   $all = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
     unset($all[$node->language]);
     if(isset($all)){
            foreach($all as $del){
                    if($node->nid != $del->nid){
                        $nids[] = $del->nid; 
                            db_delete('node')
                                ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
                                ->execute();
                            db_delete('node_revision')
                                ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
                                ->execute();
                            db_delete('history')
                                ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
                                ->execute();
                            db_delete('node_access')
                             ->condition('nid', $nids, 'IN')
                             ->execute();
                    }
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you first have to remove the nodes from the translation set before you can delete them. So do something like this:

```
function hook_node_delete($node){
    $all = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);

    foreach($all as $del){
        if($node->nid != $del->nid){
            translation_remove_from_set(node_load($del->nid));
            node_delete($del->nid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by 118218 doesn't work for me because if you are deleting the source node (first node created of the translation set) the function `translation_node_get_translations` will return `null`, since the `tnid` of the other nodes of this translation set will be updated before the execution of `hook_node_delete`.

The solution for me was to overwrite the `node/%node/delete` menu item like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function my_module_menu_alter(&$items)
{
    $items['node/%node/delete']['page arguments'] = array('my_module_custom_node_delete', 1);
    $items['node/%node/delete']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module');
    $items['node/%node/delete']['file'] = 'my_module.module';
}
```

and then implement the delete confirmation form and submit function creating a callback before the node deletion like this:

```
function my_module_custom_node_delete($form, &$form_state, $node) {
    $form['#node'] = $node;
    // Always provide entity id in the same form key as in the entity edit form.
    $form['nid'] = array('#type' => 'value', '#value' => $node->nid);
    return confirm_form($form,
        t('Are you sure you want to delete %title?', array('%title' => $node->title)),
        'node/' . $node->nid,
        t('This action cannot be undone.'),
        t('Delete'),
        t('Cancel')
    );
}

function my_module_custom_node_delete_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if ($form_state['values']['confirm']) {
        $node = node_load($form_state['values']['nid']);
        drupal_alter('before_node_delete', clone $node);
        node_delete($form_state['values']['nid']);
        watchdog('content', '@type: deleted %title.', array('@type' => $node->type, '%title' => $node->title));
        drupal_set_message(t('@type %title has been deleted.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node), '%title' => $node->title)));
    }
    $form_state['redirect'] = '<front>';
}
```

implement the deletion of the other nodes:

```
function my_module_delete_child_nodes($node) {
    if($node->language == SOURCE_NODE_LANGUAGE) {
        $all = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
        if(isset($all[SOURCE_NODE_LANGUAGE]))
            unset($all[SOURCE_NODE_LANGUAGE]);
        if(count($all) > 0) {
            $nids = array();
            foreach($all as $t) {
                $nids[] = $t->nid;
            }
            node_delete_multiple($nids);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally, you can call the deletion function from any module you want just implementing the hook `MODULE_NAME_before_node_delete_alter($node)`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_before_node_delete_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_before_node_delete_alter($node)
{
        my_module_delete_child_nodes($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As "filipedelmonte" answer says, if the source node of the translation set is deleted, then the function `translation_node_get_translations` will return null since the `tnid` of the other nodes of the translation set will be updated before the execution of `hook_node_delete`. However, his approach is too complicated. So I improved "Gert van den buijs" answer to work in all cases. The idea is to preload the translation set in all nodes:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_load().
 */
function hook_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  if (!is_array($nodes)) {
    return;
  }
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->translation_set = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_delete().
 */
function hook_node_delete($node) {
  if (is_array($node->translation_set)) {
    foreach ($node->translation_set as $del) {
      if ($node->nid != $del->nid) {
        translation_remove_from_set(node_load($del->nid));
        node_delete($del->nid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```